# Moving a knockoutjs object into a popup edit form

Tags: knockout.js

I have my webservice fed json rendering into a set of nested  tags using knockoutjs.  (works great).

So what I want to do now is have a popup edit window (already setup with KendoUI\jquery) to change the values.

Problem though is I don't know if I'm out to lunch and this is even possible...how would you pass off a bound object to something else to handle the editing?

Comment: When you call `ko.applyBindings(model)` are you passing any additional parameters after the model? It would help if you could post a slimmed down version of the JS and HTML.

Comment: Here is a sample from a while back that might help: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/.

Answer (score 5):

I do something like this in my code:

In my viewModel, I create an instance of the login function:

```
    this.loginDialog = ko.observable(new LoginDialog(this));
```

which is defined sort of like this:

```
function LoginDialog(viewModel) {
    var self = this;
    this.viewModel = viewModel;

    this.userid = ko.observable();
    this.password = ko.observable();
    this.open = ko.observable(false);
    this.message = ko.observable();

    // more here
}
```

I then have a binding called `dialog`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $(element).dialog(options || {});
        }, 0);

        //handle disposal (not strictly necessary in this scenario)
         ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
             $(element).dialog("destroy");
         });   
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
         var shouldBeOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().openWhen);
         var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
         var $elem = $(element);
         var dynamicOptions = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dynamicOpts) || {};
         $elem
            .dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");
         if (dynamicOptions.title)
             $elem.dialog("option", "title", ko.utils.unwrapObservable(dynamicOptions.title));
    }
};
```

which I call like this

```
<!--  ko with: loginDialog -->
<div id='logindlg' class="dialog"
    data-bind="dialog: {autoOpen: false, modal: true, closeOnEscape: false, title: 'Login', height: 300, width: 550, dialogClass: 'no-close', resizable: false}, openWhen: open">

 <!-- more stuff here -->
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```